# Justify box at the left margin while keeping \parindent glue/obeying \noindent if present

Tags: horizontal-alignment, boxes, plain-tex, leftmargin

How to define a command which takes two arguments and from the first argument makes a new paragraph where the right margin of a box containing the second argument is justified at the left margin of that paragraph with the reference-point of that box vertically being on the baseline of the first line of text of that paragraph?

If I do

```
\long\def\Command#1#2{\leavevmode\llap{#2}#1}

\Command{The text of the paragraph.}{Left justified?}

\Command{\noindent The text of the paragraph.}{Left justified?}

\bye
```

, then (as expected) `\noindent` has no effect and the right margin of the box containing the phrase "Left justified?" is not justified at the left margin of the paragraph but is justified at the left of the letter `T`.

If instead of `\leavevmode` I do `\noindent`, then the right margin of the box containing the phrase "Left justified?" is justified both at the left margin of the paragraph and at the left of the letter `T` but there will not be `\parindent`-glue before the letter `T` unless you add it "by hand" as a part of `\Command`'s first argument:

```
\long\def\Command#1#2{\noindent\llap{#2}#1}

\Command{The text of the paragraph.}{Left justified?}

\Command{\noindent The text of the paragraph.}{Left justified?}

\bye
```

So after spending days of parsing inscrutable ambiguous phrases of the TeXbook, I did only find ways of not achieving what I desire and I only learned why my attempts do not work.

Could somebody point out a way which **does** work?

Comment: TeXBook, Chapter 14: How TeX Breaks Paragraphs into Lines, double dangerous bend paragraph right behind exercise 14.28 says: When TeX enters horizontal mode, the following things always happen: Vertical `\parskip`-glue. Then initiating horizontal list by hbox of width `\parindent` (unless horizontal mode was initiated by `\noindent`), then the tokens held in `\everypar`, then processing the...

Comment: ... tokens that caused horizontal mode. Via `\everypar` you can "lay hands" on the `\parindent`-box via `\lastbox` which will remove the last box from the list and move it to the box-register of your choice. This is what David Carlisle did in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/560798).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I think you mean this, not entirely clear:

```
\long\def\Command#1#2{%
\everypar{\setbox0\lastbox\llap{#2}\box0\everypar{}}#1}

\Command{The text of the paragraph.}{Left justified?}

\Command{\noindent The text of the paragraph.}{Left justified?}

\bye
```

Comment: Almost. Thank you. `\Command{\hbox{This box should be part of the paragraph, too} text text}{Left justified?}` does not work out...

Comment: @MarsupialWallaby starting text with `\hbox` is an explicit instruction not to start a paragraph.

Comment: Yes. But I would like to override that with `\Command`. That's why I said " and from the first argument makes a new paragraph". The problem is ensuring that a paragraph will be started without the means applied for ensuring causing or preventing the insertion of `\parindent`-glue.

Comment: @MarsupialWallaby without your comand if your text is `\hbox{a}\hbox{b}\hbox{c}ddd`  then a b c stack vertically and the paragraph and any indentation starts at  ddd. Your llap is essentially a paragraph label as far as I can see so comes with the parindent on ddd. You could possibly do something else but I don't see what in general you can do if you are allowing non paragraph commands like hbox or vskip at the start of that argument.

Comment: note parindent is a box, not glue.

Comment: @MarsupialWallaby `\hbox` does not cause TeX to enter horizontal mode. You cannot start horizontal-mode/a paragraph by means of a `\hbox`. That's it. So your `\Command`-macro would need to check whether its first argument's first tokens are suitable for starting a paragraph. If not, the `\Command`-macro itself would have to start the new paragraph. You would need to provide specifications for this case about the question of starting the paragraph with/without `\noindent`. In the end you ask for a routine for checking whether a macro-argument's first tokens themselves are suitable...

Comment: @MarsupialWallaby  ...for starting a new paragraph. As the argument itself consists of tokens which form an algorithm, this leads to the question of examining algorithms. The halting problem comes to my mind. Besides this: You said `\Command` shall create a paragraph. What shall `\Command` do in case the 1st argument contains also tokens which end a paragraph/start another paragraph. Shall `\Command` in such cases be allowed to create more than one paragraph? What shall `\Command` do in case the 1st argument being, e.g., a math-display?

Answer (score 0):

I took your comment

> Almost. Thank you. `\Command{\hbox{This box should be part of the paragraph, too} text text}{Left justified?}` does not work out...

on [David Carlisle's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/560798) into account:

The horizontal box of width `\parindent` at the beginning of horizontal mode is produced and set without carrying out the hook `\everyhbox`.

Thus you can create a mechanism for setting an `\if...`-switch in case `\everyhbox`/`\everyvbox` is triggered before `\everypar`:

Create a temporary vertical box from `\Command`'s first argument.

While creating that temporary vertical box prepend to the hooks `\everyhbox`/`\everyvbox` a macro-token which globally sets an `\if...`-switch.
Prepend to each of the hooks  `\everyhbox`/`\everyvbox` and `\everypar` a directive to restore all these hooks.

Effect:

In case `\everypar` is carried out before `\everyvbox` or `\everyhbox`, the hooks will be restored and thus the directive to change the `\if..`-switch appended to `\everyhbox`/`\everyvbox` is gone and will never be carried out.

In case `\everyvbox` or `\everyhbox` is carried out before `\everypar`, the directive to set the `\if`-switch is carried out once and all the hooks are restored.

As three hooks (`\everypar`, `\everyvbox`, `\everyhbox`) are involved, I defined a recursive routine `\prependtorestorehooks` where you can provide a list of tuples, first component denoting a hook, second component denoting tokens for this hook to deliver before restoring all hooks in the tuple-list and delivering the tokens which the hook also delivered before redefining.

You also need some precautions in case the mechanism/`\Command` is nested.

Caveats:

- Appending to hooks/restoring hooks only works as long as the hooks themselves do not contain `\outer`-tokens. E.g., the following code yields an error-message `! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning text of \everypar.`:

  ```
  \begingroup
  \everypar={\problem}%
  \outer\def\problem{How to overcome the problem?}%
  \everypar=\expandafter{\the\everypar Again: How to overcome the problem?}%
  \endgroup
  \bye
  ```
- `\everyhbox`/`\everyvbox` is triggered when creating a `\hbox`/`\vbox` no matter if that box makes it into the output-file or goes into a box-register whose content will never make it into the output-file. Thus the mechanism can be fooled by placing, e.g., a `\setbox`-assignment in the beginning of `\Command`'s argument.
- A temporary `\vbox` is created from `\Command`'s first argument for setting the `\if...`-switch in case `\everyhbox`/`\everyvbox` is triggered before `\everypar`. Thus the material of `\Command`'s first argument is processed twice: Once for creating the temporary box. Once for creating the paragraph that should go into the output-file. There might be things like `\immediate\write` which you don't want to have carried out twice. Unfortunately there is no "get-box-properties"/"box-measuring"-mode where such things could be turned off.

```
\long\def\firstoftwo#1#2{#1}%
\long\def\secondoftwo#1#2{#2}%
%\prependtorestorehooks{%
%  {{hook 1}{prepend 1}}%
%  {{hook 2}{prepend 2}}%
%  ...
%}%
\long\def\prependtorestorehooks#1{%
  \prependtorestorehookscreraterestore{}{#1}#1\relax
}%
\long\def\prependtorestorehookscreraterestore#1#2#3{%
  % #1 - Restore-List created so far
  % #2 - entire list
  % #3 - next element
  \ifx\relax#3\expandafter\firstoftwo\else\expandafter\secondoftwo\fi
  {\prependtorestorehooksprependtohooks{}{#1}#2\relax}%
  {%
    \prependtorestorehooksextract#3{#1}{#2}%
  }%
}%
\long\def\prependtorestorehooksextract#1#2{%
  \expandafter\prependtorestorehooksextractinner\expandafter{\the#1}{#1}%
}%
\long\def\prependtorestorehooksextractinner#1#2#3{%
  \prependtorestorehookscreraterestore{#3#2={#1}}%
}%
\long\def\prependtorestorehooksprependtohooks#1#2#3{%
  %#1 prepend-list-created so far
  %#2 restore-list
  %#3 {hook}{prepend}
  \ifx\relax#3\expandafter\firstoftwo\else\expandafter\secondoftwo\fi
  {#1}{%
     \prependtorestorehooksprependtohooksb#3{#1}{#2}%
  }%
}%
\long\def\prependtorestorehooksprependtohooksb#1{%
  \expandafter\prependtorestorehooksprependtohooksc\expandafter{\the#1}{#1}%
}%
\long\def\prependtorestorehooksprependtohooksc#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \prependtorestorehooksprependtohooks{#4#2={#3#5#1}}{#5}%
}%
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newbox\MyBox
\newif\ifleadingbox
\newif\ifintestbox\intestboxfalse
\newif\ifhookdone\hookdonefalse
\def\firstindent{}%
\long\def\setifleadingboxandfirstindent#1{%
  \begingroup
  \ifintestbox\else\global\hookdonefalse\global\leadingboxfalse\fi
  \setbox\MyBox=\vbox{%
    \intestboxtrue
    \prependtorestorehooks{%
     {{\everypar}{\ifhookdone\else\setbox\MyBox=\lastbox\xdef\firstindent{\the\wd\MyBox}\box\MyBox\global\hookdonetrue\fi}}%
     {{\everyhbox}{\ifhookdone\else\global\leadingboxtrue\global\hookdonetrue\fi}}%
     {{\everyvbox}{\ifhookdone\else\global\leadingboxtrue\global\hookdonetrue\fi}}%
    }%
    #1%
  }%
  \endgroup
}%
\long\def\Command#1#2{%
  \par
  \setifleadingboxandfirstindent{#1}%
  \prependtorestorehooks{{{\everypar}{\setbox\MyBox\lastbox\llap{#2}\box\MyBox}}}%
  \ifleadingbox\leavevmode\else\noindent\hbox to\firstindent{\hfill}\fi#1%
}%

\leavevmode

\kern-1in

\noindent test \hfill test \hfill test

\setifleadingboxandfirstindent{a}%
\ifleadingbox some \else no \fi leading h-or vbox.
\ifleadingbox\else Paragraph is indented by: \firstindent\fi

\smallskip\hrule\smallskip

\setifleadingboxandfirstindent{\hbox{a}}%
\ifleadingbox some \else no \fi leading h-or vbox.
\ifleadingbox\else Paragraph is indented by: \firstindent\fi

\smallskip\hrule\smallskip

\setifleadingboxandfirstindent{\vbox{a}}%
\ifleadingbox some \else no \fi leading h-or vbox.
\ifleadingbox\else Paragraph is indented by: \firstindent\fi

\smallskip\hrule\smallskip

\setifleadingboxandfirstindent{\noindent\vbox{a}}%
\ifleadingbox some \else no \fi leading h-or vbox.
\ifleadingbox\else Paragraph is indented by: \firstindent\fi

\smallskip\hrule\smallskip

\noindent {\bf Test 1:}

\Command{The text of the paragraph.}{Left justified?}

\smallskip\hrule\smallskip

\noindent {\bf Test 2:}

\Command{\noindent The text of the paragraph.}{Left justified?}

\smallskip\hrule\smallskip

\noindent {\bf Test 3:}

\Command{\hbox to 5cm{The\hfill wide\hfill text} of the paragraph.}{Left justified?}

\smallskip\hrule\smallskip

\noindent {\bf Test 4:}

\Command{\noindent\hbox to 5cm{The\hfill wide\hfill text} of the paragraph.}{Left justified?}

\smallskip\hrule\smallskip

\noindent {\bf Test 5:}

\Command{\vtop{\hbox to 5cm{The\hfill wide\hfill text}\hbox to 5cm{The\hfill wide\hfill text}} of the paragraph.}{Left justified?}

\smallskip\hrule\smallskip

\noindent {\bf Test 6:}

\Command{\noindent\vtop{\hbox to 5cm{The\hfill wide\hfill text}\hbox to 5cm{The\hfill wide\hfill text}} of the paragraph.}{Left justified?}

\smallskip\hrule\smallskip

\noindent {\bf Test 7:}

\Command{\vbox{\hbox to 5cm{The\hfill wide\hfill text}\hbox to 5cm{The\hfill wide\hfill text}} of the paragraph.}{Left justified?}

\smallskip\hrule\smallskip

\noindent {\bf Test 8:}

\Command{\noindent\vbox{\hbox to 5cm{The\hfill wide\hfill text}\hbox to 5cm{The\hfill wide\hfill text}} of the paragraph.}{Left justified?}

\smallskip\hrule\smallskip

\noindent {\bf Test 9:}

\newdimen\MyDimen
\setbox\MyBox=\hbox{Left justified?}
\MyDimen=\wd\MyBox

\Command{\noindent\kern\MyDimen The text of the paragraph.}{Left justified?}

\smallskip\hrule\smallskip

\noindent {\bf Test 10:}

\Command{\leavevmode\kern\MyDimen The text of the paragraph.}{Left justified?}

\smallskip\hrule\smallskip

\noindent {\bf Test 11:}

\Command{\noindent\kern\MyDimen \hbox{\vbox{\advance\hsize-\MyDimen\Command{\noindent The text of the paragraph.}{Left justified?}}}}{Left justified?}

\smallskip\hrule\smallskip

\noindent {\bf Test 12:}

\Command{\noindent\kern\MyDimen \hbox{\vbox{\advance\hsize-\MyDimen\Command{The text of the paragraph.}{Left justified?}}}}{Left justified?}

\smallskip\hrule\smallskip

\noindent {\bf Test 13:}

\Command{\leavevmode\kern\MyDimen \hbox{\vbox{\advance\hsize-\MyDimen\advance\hsize-\parindent\Command{\noindent The text of the paragraph.}{Left justified?}}}}{Left justified?}

\smallskip\hrule\smallskip

\noindent {\bf Test 14:}

\Command{\leavevmode\kern\MyDimen \hbox{\vbox{\advance\hsize-\MyDimen\advance\hsize-\parindent\Command{The text of the paragraph.}{Left justified?}}}}{Left justified?}

\smallskip\hrule\smallskip

\noindent {\bf Test 15:}

\Command{\kern\MyDimen The text of the paragraph.}{Left justified?}

\smallskip\hrule\smallskip

\noindent {\bf Test 16:}

% `\Command` starts with `\par`, i.e., by resorting to (restricted) vertical mode. Thus \kerns at the beginning of \Command's first argument in any case are vertical.

\Command{\kern\MyDimen\noindent The text of the paragraph.}{Left justified?}

\smallskip\hrule\smallskip

\noindent {\bf Test 17:}

% `\Command` starts with `\par`, i.e., by resorting to (restricted) vertical mode. Thus \kerns at the beginning of \Command's first argument in any case are vertical.

\Command{\kern\MyDimen\hbox{T}he text of the paragraph.}{Left justified?}

\smallskip\hrule\bigskip

\noindent {\bf Test 18:}

\Command{The text of the paragraph. \par  The text of the paragraph.  \par  The text of the paragraph.\Command{\noindent The text of the paragraph. \par  The text of the paragraph. \par  The text of the paragraph.}{Left justified?}}{Left justified?}


\smallskip\hrule\bigskip

\noindent{\bf !!!! But: !!!}

\bigskip

\noindent {\bf Test 19:}

\Command{\setbox\MyBox=\hbox{Something to trigger the every-hook}\noindent This text is indented although it should not be indented. The reason is the triggering of {\tt\string\everyhbox} by {\tt\string\setbox...} right at the beginning of {\tt\string\Command}'s first argument.}{Left justified?}

\bye
```

[image]

To be honest:

I don't know why all this is needed. In the manual of `\Command` just tell that TeX switches to vertical mode before processing `#1`. The user can decide her-/himself if explicit `\leavevmode` or `\noindent` is needed for switching to horizontal-mode.